# Linear Gradient Background Image - CSS Not working

Tags: css

This is my `styles.css` which contains:

```css
.ui.inverted.top.fixed.menu {
    background-image:linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(24,42,115) 0%, rgb (33, 138, 174) 69%, rgb(32,167,172) 89%);
    background-image: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(24,42,115) 0%, rgb (33, 138, 174) 69%, rgb(32,167,172) 89%);
    background-image: -moz-repeating-linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(24,42,115) 0%, rgb (33, 138, 174) 69%, rgb(32,167,172) 89%) ;
    background-image: -ms-repeating-linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(24,42,115) 0%, rgb (33, 138, 174) 69%, rgb(32,167,172) 89%) ;
    background-image: -o-repeating-linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(24,42,115) 0%, rgb (33, 138, 174) 69%, rgb(32,167,172) 89%) ;
    background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(24,42,115) 0%, rgb (33, 138, 174) 69%, rgb(32,167,172) 89%) ; 
}
```

The reason it has so many versions is because I want to show I have tried all possibilities in all the browsers and can't figure out why it's not working. The browser developer shows me it as an invalid property value.

This is what my HTML DOM looks like where I am trying to apply this:

[image]

Comment: I updated my answer for a new point. please check it.

Comment: both the answers below are correct. how do i know who answered it first? it says the same time for me.

Comment: Rafael's answer did some seconds early. So accept his answer.

Comment: @Baahubali -- for future reference, if you hover the answered time (where it says "answered yesterday", or "answered an hour ago") with your cursor, eventually you will get a tooltip showing the exact timestamp of when they answered.  Good luck, and happy coding!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There're a space between `rgb` and start parentheses  `(` in every `background-image` property.

You need Remove theses spaces:

- Before: `rgb (`
- After: `rgb(`

Example:

```css
.ui.inverted.top.fixed.menu {
  height: 426px;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(24, 42, 115) 0%, rgb(33, 138, 174) 69%, rgb(32, 167, 172) 89%);
  background: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(24, 42, 115) 0%, rgb (33, 138, 174) 69%, rgb(32, 167, 172) 89%);
  background: -moz-repeating-linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(24, 42, 115) 0%, rgb(33, 138, 174) 69%, rgb(32, 167, 172) 89%);
  background: -ms-repeating-linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(24, 42, 115) 0%, rgb(33, 138, 174) 69%, rgb(32, 167, 172) 89%);
  background: -o-repeating-linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(24, 42, 115) 0%, rgb(33, 138, 174) 69%, rgb(32, 167, 172) 89%);
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(24, 42, 115) 0%, rgb(33, 138, 174) 69%, rgb(32, 167, 172) 89%);
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <div class="ui inverted top fixed menu">
    <div class="ui container"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It was interesting:)

Comment: i didn't know this space mattered :(.

Answer (score 2):

It works for me fine. only I deleted a space between `rgb` and `(` in the first background-image:

```css
.ui.inverted.top.fixed.menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(24, 42, 115) 0%, rgb(33, 138, 174) 69%, rgb(32, 167, 172) 89%);
  background-image: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(24, 42, 115) 0%, rgb (33, 138, 174) 69%, rgb(32, 167, 172) 89%);
  background-image: -moz-repeating-linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(24, 42, 115) 0%, rgb (33, 138, 174) 69%, rgb(32, 167, 172) 89%);
  background-image: -ms-repeating-linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(24, 42, 115) 0%, rgb (33, 138, 174) 69%, rgb(32, 167, 172) 89%);
  background-image: -o-repeating-linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(24, 42, 115) 0%, rgb (33, 138, 174) 69%, rgb(32, 167, 172) 89%);
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(24, 42, 115) 0%, rgb (33, 138, 174) 69%, rgb(32, 167, 172) 89%);
}
```

```html
<div class="ui inverted top fixed menu">
</div>
```

**Edit:**

also, I realized there is this space in other lines. But when I remove spaces, makes a color dark blue at the end of linear-gradient. seem it is for a `repeating` prefix in other cases of background images:

[image]

do you want that? I do not think. So I remove those(-repeating). Now how it is?

```css
.ui.inverted.top.fixed.menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(24, 42, 115) 0%, rgb(33, 138, 174) 69%, rgb(32, 167, 172) 89%);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(24, 42, 115) 0%, rgb(33, 138, 174) 69%, rgb(32, 167, 172) 89%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(24, 42, 115) 0%, rgb(33, 138, 174) 69%, rgb(32, 167, 172) 89%);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(24, 42, 115) 0%, rgb(33, 138, 174) 69%, rgb(32, 167, 172) 89%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(24, 42, 115) 0%, rgb(33, 138, 174) 69%, rgb(32, 167, 172) 89%);
}
```

```html
<div class="ui inverted top fixed menu">
</div>
```

But changes the direction of linear-gradient. It fixes If remove other background images:

```css
.ui.inverted.top.fixed.menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(24, 42, 115) 0%, rgb(33, 138, 174) 69%, rgb(32, 167, 172) 89%);
}
```

```html
<div class="ui inverted top fixed menu">
</div>
```

Comment: i didn't know this space mattered :(.